# Find $\int \frac {x^2}{x^3+1} dx$. What is my mistake?

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int \frac {x^2}{x^3+1} dx$

$ u = 3x+1, du=3x^2 dx$

$\int \frac{3 du}{u} $

Am I wrong something? Why the answer is $\int \frac{du}{3u}$ instead of $\int \frac{3 du}{u} $ ?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe you meant $u = x^3+1$, not $u=3x+1$.

Comment: After @ClementC.'s fix, $x^2 dx = \frac{du}3$.

Comment: If u = 3x + 1 then du = 3 dt which leads to $\int ([u-1]/3)^2/3[(u-1/3)^3 + 1] du$ which is ... worse.

Answer (score 2):

Set $t=x^3+1$ and $dt=3x^2dx$

Therefore $\color{red}{ x^2dx=\frac{du}{3}}$

$$=\frac 1 3\int \frac 1 t dt =\frac{\ln t}{3}+\mathcal C=\boxed{\color{blue}{\frac 1 3 \ln (x^3+1)+\mathcal C}} $$

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you set $u=x^3+1$ (so that $du = 3x^2dx$), then $x^2dx = \frac{du}{3}$ and 
$$
\int \frac{x^2 dx}{x^3 +1} = \int \frac{\frac{du}{3}}{u} =\int  \frac{du}{3u}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You have:

$$
u=x^3+1 \rightarrow du=3x^2dx \rightarrow x^2dx=\frac{du}{3} 
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=x^3+1$ then you have your $du=3x^2dx$, then from your original equation $x^2dx$ is just equal to $\frac{du}{3}$. Now solving for the whole equation that just equal to $\int\frac{du}{3u}$.

$\int\frac{du}{3u}=\frac{1}{3}\int\frac{du}{u}=\frac{1}{3}lnu+ C= \frac{1}{3}ln(x^3+1)+C.$

Answer (score 0):

A more rigoures approach.

$$ \int \frac{x^2}{x^3+1} dx $$
$$ u = x^3 +1 $$
$$ \frac{du}{dx}  = 3x^2 $$

so:

$$ \frac{1}{3} \int \frac{3x^2}{x^3+1} dx =  \frac{1}{3}  Ln |x^3 +1| + K$$